# implement UIScrollview on a particular area of screen?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

i am creating an app which has two ***UIImageViews*** at top and bottom of the screen and few customs buttons in between them which i am using in a ***UIScrollview*** so that user can scroll through them while the two images remain on top & bottom as they are.But when i use the scrollview the buttons scroll over the two UIimageview instead of just scrolling between them or hiding behind them as users scroll down..how can i make the ***UIImagviews*** remain on top of the buttons in ***UIScrollview***??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you use the Interface Builder...

Make sure that:

- The frame of the scroll view is between the image view
- The Clip subviews of the scroll view is checked
- The image views appear after the scroll view in the views hierarchy (if not then you can just drag them inside the hierarchy)

Comment: thank you that really helped!!
also i want these two UIImagview to remain at there place while user navigates to different pages on clicking buttons within the scrollview..any idea how i can achieve that??

Comment: You might add these 2 image views on each screen that you want them to appear. Or, if you want these to appear on all the screens, then you might create one main view controller with a main view that will contain these image views and the navigation controller with all the leaf view controllers will be located right between the image views. In this case all the transformations of views will be done without moving the image views...